# pandas filtering for row values

Tags: python, pandas

(df[col1] == value1) | (df[col1] == value2)

For filtering for some reason I remember a shorter version:

df[col] == (value1 or value2)

Might be crossing languages by mistake, but I remember a short version.

Comment: All suggestions good. Thank you. Do u know why there is an error when OR is used instead of | (pipe)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

```
>>> df
     A
0   20
1   30
2  500

>>> df['A'].isin([20, 30])
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool

>>> (df['A'] == 20) | (df['A'] == 30)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

You can check [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for more examples

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean `.isin`:

```py
df['col1'].isin(['value1', 'value2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest to your idea that comes to my mind is this:

```
df[df['col1'].isin(['value1','value2'])]
```

Comment: So works as an OR, values in columns are members of a list. What about AND situation (like value = 1.0, isinstance(value, float) AND value.is_integer().